# Yii-2 how to update a record on basis of id

Tags: php, yii2, updatemodel

I want to update my `table/model`. The scenario is, I have a 'status' column, I want to `SET` this column to a value then update the model based on the `id`. I want to do something like `update` statement.

`Update 'table' SET status = 'status value' where id = 'myid'`

My `action controller` look like

```
$model = $this->findModel($id);
$ogp_id = $model->id;
$status = $model->status;
```

I have searched for it but couldn't find a solution

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Works for me

I added a function

```
 protected function findModel($id)
{
    if (($model = Ogpheader::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

Then access it inside the controller

```
$model = $this->findModel($id);
$ogp_id = $model->id;
```

Then while saving my model I have done the following

```
if($m->save())
{
   $model->status = Ogpheader::$status_titles[1];
   $model->update();
   //my other code
}
```

This has updated my table and set the column as required

Comment: Do you know the reason for the down vote on his answer? although I didn't but my first guess is `$this->findModel()` as this is a custom function inside your controller and there is no function provided inside your code so this would result in an error if someone copy and paste your code and try to run, you should correct the answer or you will get more downvotes on this answer

Answer (score 6):

for retrive the $id related  model 
You can use findOne($id)  if id is the primary key

```
$model =YourModel::findOne($id);
$model->status = 'Active';
$model->save();
```

or find()->Where()->one() in general cases

```
$model =YourModel::find()-where(['id'=>$id])->one();
$model->status = 'Active';
$model->save();
```

if your validation rules fail you can try using `$model->save(false);`  if in this case e row is updated  thin mean that some of your data don't respect validation rules .. and you should check for this

Comment: you have already marked  as answered  another answer   .. so what mean your comment ?????

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

```
  $model =Table::find($id);
    $model->status = 'Active';
    $model->save();
```

also use Create command can be used directly as follows :

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE table SET status=:status WHERE id=:id")
->bindValue(':id', your_id)
->execute();
```

Comment: `$model = $this->findModel($id);` shouldn't it work ?